# SQL Server - select min date and id from foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select, min

These are my tables:

USER:

```
id_user      name            email               last_access         id_company
  1        jhonatan       abc@abc.com            2014-12-15             1
  2         cesar          cef@cef.com           2014-12-31             1
  3         john          123@123.com            2015-01-09             2
  4         steven       897@asdd.cpom           2015-01-02             2
  5         greg           sd@touch.com          2014-12-07             1
  6          kyle           fb@fb.com            2014-11-20             1
```

COMPANY:

```
id_company                company
   1                      Facebook
   2                      Appslovers
```

I need to know, what are the users which has the MIN last_access per company (just one). It could be like this:

```
id_user              name              last_access              company
  6                  kyle              2014-11-20               Facebook
  4                 steven             2015-01-02              Appslovers
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes. `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`. What stops you from doing it yourself?

Comment: I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What **do** you know about SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window function`

```
SELECT id_user,
       NAME,
       last_access,
       company
FROM   (SELECT id_user,
               NAME,
               last_access,
               company,
               Row_number()OVER(partition BY company ORDER BY last_access) rn
        FROM   users u
               JOIN company c
                 ON u.id_company = c.id_company) a
WHERE  rn = 1
```

or `join` both the tables find the min `last_access` date per `company` then join the result back to the `users` table to get the result

```
SELECT id_user,
       NAME,
       a.last_access,
       a.company
FROM   users u
       JOIN(SELECT u.id_company,
                   Min(last_access) last_access,
                   company
            FROM   users u
                   JOIN company c
                     ON u.id_company = c.id_company
            GROUP  BY u.id_company,
                      company) a
         ON a.id_company = u.id_company
            AND u.last_access = a.last_access
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways, for example by using a window function like row_number to partition the data and then selecting the top rows from each group like this:

```
;with cte (id_user, name, last_access, company, seq) as (
    select 
       id_user, 
       name, 
       last_access, 
       company, 
       seq = row_number() over (partition by u.id_company order by last_access) 
    from [user] u
    inner join [company] c on u.id_company = c.id_company
)

select id_user, name, last_access, company  
from cte where seq = 1
```